# PySide6 signal connect positional arguments error

Tags: python, signals-slots, pyside6

I'm trying to port some code from PyQt5 to PySide6 but run into the following problem. The code below works in PyQt5 (with appropriate changes in commenting), but not in PySide6.

```
#from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtWidgets
#from PyQt5.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR, PYQT_VERSION_STR
from PySide6 import QtCore,QtWidgets
from PySide6 import __version__ as PYQT_VERSION_STR
from PySide6.QtCore import __version__ as QT_VERSION_STR


class DynamicTupleSignal(QtCore.QObject):
    signal = QtCore.Signal(tuple)
    #signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(tuple)
    def connect(self,func):
        self.signal.connect(func)

    def emit(self,data):
        self.signal.emit(data)

class TestDynamicTupleSignal:
    dynsig=DynamicTupleSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        self.dynsig.connect(self.whattheheck)

    def whattheheck(self,data):
        print(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    print("Python Version",sys.version)
    print("PyQt5/PySide6 Version:",PYQT_VERSION_STR)
    print("Qt Version:",QT_VERSION_STR)
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    w.show()
    sig=TestDynamicTupleSignal()
    app.exec()
```

With PySide6 I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\data\src\test.py", line 42, in <module>
    sig=TestDynamicTupleSignal()
  File "c:\data\src\test.py", line 29, in __init__
    self.dynsig.connect(self.whattheheck)
  File "c:\data\src\test.py", line 20, in connect
    self.signal.connect(func)
TypeError: connect() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Version information

```
Python Version 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
PySide6 Version: 6.5.1.1
Qt Version: 6.5.1

PyQt5 Version: 5.12.3
Qt Version: 5.12.10
```

Is it a bug or something I have misunderstood?

Thanks

Comment: Try changing the `connect` method name to something else, like `connectFunc`: `def connectFunc(self, func):` and `self.dynsig.connectFunc(self.whattheheck)`. Note that using generic names for methods of objects that inherit from complex subclasses is usually discouraged and should always be done with care: while your code seems perfectly fine, wrappers like PySide and PyQt actually use complex systems to "bind" the python objects to their C++ counterparts (including method names that are statically bound). `connect` is an existing function of all QObjects, and should *never* be overwritten.

Comment: Thanks @musicamante ! That of cause solves it. I tried to keep the names `connect` and `emit` and call `super(...).connect(...)`, but couldn't make it work. Can't that be done?

Comment: Why would you do that? The `QObject.connect()` method is for a very specific syntax (see the documentation), while you just want to connect a function to a predefined signal. Just use another name.

Comment: Because the basic functionality is the same as a standard signal, thus it is more intuitive if the methods with same purpose has the same name. But, thank anyway, it is not important.